# I'm trying to make a generated column in one table, that contains the number of rows there are in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have table A and table B. Table B needs to have a column "atr1" that counts how many rows there are in table B and also the number of columns can't exceed a constant number that's specified in another column in table B called "atr2".

I tried doing this:

```
    alter table B
    alter column atr1 type integer generated always as(count(*) from A) check (atr1 < atr2) not null;
```

but it gives me a syntax error at or near generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated columns can only refer to calculations on columns in the table itself. If you need to know the count from a different table, you will need to create a view instead.